# Java float Range Limiting

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm currently working on an assignment and for the most part, I have a working program. The problem I'm having is creating a condition for this program, because, unfortunately, I am required to use the float data type. The assignment requires that I have an interface and multiple classes set up for three different shapes. One of them, being circles. For the circle's input, it requires a radius and an angle (just for the sectors) and it calculates the whole circle's perimeter and area as well as the sector's perimeter and area. I need the angle of the circle sectors to be greater than 0 and less than 360 degrees. The radius must also be greater than 0.

Here's what I have so far for error checking:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\nPlease input the angle of a circle sector: ");

while (!userInput.hasNextFloat())
{
    System.out.print("Error. Incorrect input. Please enter a number: ");
    userInput.next();
}

float circleAngle = userInput.nextFloat();

    while (circleAngle > 0 && circleAngle < 360)
    {
        System.out.print("You have an invalid entry.");
        System.out.print("Please input an angle greater than 0 and less than 360:");
        circleAngle = userInput.nextFloat();
    }

System.out.print("\nPlease input the radius of the circle Sector: ");

while (!userInput.hasNextFloat())
{
    System.out.print("Error. Incorrect input. Please enter a number: ");
    userInput.next();
}


float circleRadius = userInput.nextFloat();

Circle myCircle = new Circle(circleAngle, circleRadius);
myCircle.setPerimeter();
myCircle.setArea();
myCircle.setSectorArea();
myCircle.setSectorPerimeter();


System.out.println("Whole Circle perimeter: "+myCircle.getPerimeter());
System.out.println("Whole Circle Area: "+myCircle.getArea());
System.out.println("Circle Sector perimeter: "+myCircle.getSectorPerimeter());
System.out.println("Circle Sector Area: "+myCircle.getSectorArea());
```

As you can see, I'm not having much luck regarding limiting the range of the float inputs. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a question of luck. It's a question of writing some code to do it. loop until you have a correct value. Try something.

Comment: And to add to the comment above, I recommend not using Scanner but instead put the logic in a method.  Loop the user through the input until you have the desired result.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how you can limit the range of the float values without writing some code.

Comment: Continuing from @menefee suggestion, a possible method design could be `private float getValidFloatWithinRange(float low, float high)` which would loop until the user gave a valid value between the two parameters.

Comment: I am required to also have user input. I can't automatically loop the input in. The instructor wants it to be interactive.

Comment: @JonathonP. Yes that is what all the suggestions have been

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're saying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research. I discovered I could place a while statement that forced conditions upon previous userInput such as circleAngle in the code above. Afterwards, I came up with the solution to my question as it follows:

```
while (circleAngle <= 0 || circleAngle >= 360)
{
    System.out.print("You have an invalid entry.");
    System.out.print("Please input an angle greater than 0 and less than 360:");
    circleAngle = userInput.nextFloat();
}
```

This allowed me to loop the input until a valid value was given. I plan to add more to the rest of the code.

Thanks to all who helped.